# Extracting data from a vector in increments - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How can I extract data from a vector as a series of blocks? I am not able to think of a concise, efficient way to do this.

For example, if I have a vector containing block sizes:

```
a=

4
20
5
14
9
```

And a second vector `b` containing a continuous set of data

```
b=

1
1
0
1
1
0
1
1
1
1
0
1
1
1
1
0
and so on.
```

As part of a loop, the desired output would be to populate `c` with `b(1:4)` in the first iteration (as `a(1) = 4`), however in the second iteration it would then take `b(5:24)` (as `a(2) = 20`). This continues, taking the next 5 points along. The length of `b` always equals the summation of `a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use cumsum(a) to build an index of stop points.  The start points are then all but the last points of the cumsum + 1.

```
idx = cumsum(a)';
s_idx = [1; idx(1:end-1) + 1];
```

then index through as

```
for x = 1:length(idx)
    w(...) = b(s_idx(x):idx(x));
end
```

Comment: You can probably avoid creating a copy of `idx` by prepending it with 0, starting the loop at 2, and extracting `b(1+idx(x-1):idx(x)`

Answer (score 2):

You can also chunk the array into elements of a cell array using [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html?refresh=true):

```
>> c = mat2cell(b,a)
c = 
    [ 4x1 double]
    [20x1 double]
    [ 5x1 double]
    [14x1 double]
    [ 9x1 double]
```